# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosts' of undefined - useQuery hook, react Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client, react-functional-component

I did try searching for the same question but all of those were of either angular or unrelated,

I am trying to make a **Social app using MongoDB, Express, React, Node, Graphql with Apollo**, I am following a video from freecodecamp : [Link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1mdAPFq2Os)
In that video everything worked fine but in his deployed version he is having the same error as mine

> react_devtools_backend.js:2450 TypeError:
>
> Cannot read property 'getPosts' of undefined
>
> at ae (Home.js:14)
> at Jo (react-dom.production.min.js:3274)

[link to the deployed app](https://gracious-shannon-271ede.netlify.app/)

**My Code:** **I am dropping a link to my github repo** containing the whole project : [Link to github
repo](https://github.com/lorstenoplo/merng-app)

**Stack Overflow was throwing too many indentation issues so i have linked my github above** as there
is too much of code

- I'm using semantic-ui for styling
- I'm using graphql the fetch posts from MongoDB
- Apollo Client for rendering data

This is the error I am getting in the Home.js:
**Screen Shot of the error:**

[image: error screen shot]

Comment: READ DOCS! 'data' CAN be undefined when in loading state ... `if(loading) { return "loading" };` before main return (and destructuring or any acces to deeper 'data' property) prevents this kind of errors

Comment: Can you please help me with the code, like can you post the code as answer?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#example-2  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query

Comment: I followed the docs now i am rendering the code conditionally but still facing the same error

Comment: ehhhh, look at network tab - response contains error - bad data, bad results ... `error` can be derived from hook, too and should block rendering like loading

Comment: nothing like that everything has a status code of 304 and no error

Comment: should be 200 for POST, always ... "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.username." 54-th item is nulled  ...  render jsoned 'posts' (or insert 'debugger' before return) to check it ... disable minification, it's hard to check where points error displayed in console

Comment: code please, I am a beginner and hence it's for me to understand what you are trying to say

Comment: `if(data) console.log(posts);` before return

Comment: now it says data is undefined

Comment: in debugger? 'data' can be undefined at first (run - F5), later, after response (and 2nd rendering) it will be filled with data this should show array 'posts' (if no error)

Comment: no use same error I think I should just **drop this project**, anyways **I am really sorry** to waste such a huge time of yours @xadm and thanks for bearing me for such a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it simpler to debug, instead:

> const {
> loading,
> data: { getPosts: posts }
> } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

do:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
if(data) {
  console.log(data);
  const { getPosts: posts } = data;
}
if(error) {
  console.log(error);
  return "error"; // blocks rendering
}
```

> this works but not when data is there and not always

"not when data", "not always"??? weird ... 'posts' can be defined only if `data` exists ... accessing it when undefined will fail, always ... you must check 'data'

**You can/should render items (posts) ONLY when:**

- `!loading`

**AND**

- `data != undefined` - `if(data)` or `(data &&`  in JSX

  ```
   {loading && <h1>Loading posts..</h1>}
   {data && (
     <Transition.Group>
       {posts &&
         posts.map((post) => (
           <Grid.Column key={post.id} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
             <PostCard post={post} />
           </Grid.Column>
         ))}
     </Transition.Group>
   )}
  ```

Comment: **Thanks your debugging trick worked** now I am able to get know what actually the error is, I am getting network errors that is the issue by the line in which you wrote return error

Answer (score 2):

use this code like this

const { loading, data: { posts } = {} } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

Comment: usable ... for one depth level only

Comment: Some people might need a bit more explanation on [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) to better understand your answer.

Comment: it's needed to define data as an object.

sets the default as an empty object which was the old behaviour.

Comment: old? HOCs? ... if you're refactoring to hooks then you can use new behaviour (undefined `data`) - you can use `if(!data)` as general not-ready condition, not relying on some, deeper (also undefined) prop

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the query operation like:

```
export const FETCH_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  query GetPosts {
    getPosts {
      // fields
    }
  }
`
```

Alternatively, you can make use of [`alias`](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to easily reference them.

```
export const FETCH_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  query GetPosts {
    posts: getPosts {
      // fields
    }
  }
`

const {
  loading,
  data: { posts } // uses alias directly. no need to rename
} = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined`

Comment: @GayatriDipali, updated the answer to explicitly show a complete gql statement.

Comment: it worked for me just for one minute and now it's throwing the same error

Comment: It may be unrelated to `Home.js`. Maybe `SinglePost.js`?

Answer (score 1):

```
const { loading, data: { getPosts: posts } = {} } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY)
```

This should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

THIS WILL WORK

write data.getPosts inside the grid

const { loading ,data , error } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);

if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

```
    {loading ? (<h1>Loading posts...</h1>) 
    : (data.getPosts &&
      data.getPosts.map((post) => (
        <Grid.Column key={post.id} style= {{ marginBottom: 20}}>
          <PostCard post={post} />
        </Grid.Column>
```